# Why am I getting a "405 Method not allowed" error on "Put" operations through a WCF Resful service?

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, wcf-rest

I've got a simple WCF service which takes json as input/output parameters.
It works correctly as a SOAP based service and I get the expected results.

I have added RESTFul endpoints to the service.
I'm using "Google-based" PostMan to test the service.

**I can successfully call "Get" methods on the service and return JSON results:**

```
 [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Test/{calcID}", 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    CalcResults GetTestResults(string calcID);
```

When I attempt to access my "Put" based methods I get a status of:
          405 Method Not Allowed

**The signature for the "Put" method:**

```
 [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "Post",
        UriTemplate = "/GetCalculation", 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    CalcResults GetCalculation(CalcInput inputValues);
```

**This is the output that I see in the PostMan output window:**

```
<body>
   <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Service</p>
      <p>Method not allowed.</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

This is what my configuration settings look like for the endpoints for the RESTFul interface:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="CalcServiceLibrary.CalcService">

        <endpoint address="regular" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="wsHTTPEndPoints"
          contract="CalcServiceLibrary.ICalcService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" name="wsWebHTTPEndPoint"
                  contract="CalcServiceLibrary.ICalcServiceRESTful"
                  behaviorConfiguration="RESTfulBehavior" bindingConfiguration="crossDomain">
            <identity>
              <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>          
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RESTfulBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I'm sure that there is something that is not quite correct in my configuration definitions.
I've researched several posts, but have not been able to come up with the solution.

**NEW NOTE::**
I've added the following simple endpoint to my service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
    Method = "POST",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string TestPost(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + "!";
}
```

I'm testing using Postman. Here is a screen shot of my Postman screen:
[image: Postman Input Screenshot]

This is what I see in the output:
[image: Postman Output Screenshot]

This feels like it has to be some sort of configuration issue.
Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're specifying post instead of put as the method in the declaration, perhaps change to:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
       UriTemplate = "/GetCalculation", 
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
   CalcResults GetCalculation(CalcInput inputValues);
```

Comment: IR: Thanks for the quick feedback. I tried changing it to "Put" and I get the same results in Postman. Thoughts?

Comment: Been awhile since I use WCF, I typically just did POST instead of messing with PUT. Would indeed help to see the code that is sending the request as @Ian suggests.

Comment: IR: I don't have access to the code sending the request. I was using "PostMan" to test with. As I mentioned above, when I used Method="*", it started to work. Not sure why and not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: I wonder if it's case sensitive. I hadn't really thought about it prior, but I bet that is why Method="*" is working for you but Method="Put" does not. I'll correct the code in my answer as I had just used the same style without thinking. Checking old code and the docs it is always in uppercase.

Comment: IR: That is exactly it. It is CASE sensitive. In all the doc, etc. I looked, nowhere did it say it needed to be all CAPITOL letters. THX!

Comment: @JohnB Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

When troubleshooting the first thing I try to do is start with the bare essentials.  I'd recommend dropping the `UriTemplate = "/GetCalculation"` and `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)` attribute parameters.  This is what I have which is working:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
    Method = "POST",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string TestPost(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + "!";
}
```

*Edit:*
I thought I'd have a look at Postman, since I'm doing a lot of similar work anyway.  Can you post a screenshot of your Postman configuration?  In order to get Postman to work I had to set the following:

[image: Postman headers and POST setting]

Type is set to POST (obviously).  But I also had to set the header `Content-Type` to `application/json`.

In order to send data, you can't use URL parameters (the 'Params' button next to the URL field).  This only inserts in the style `?name=bob`, which works for `GET` but not `POST`.  Also I couldn't specify the data as JSON, so I had to enter `raw` data in JSON format:

[image: Postman body text and valid response]

Then I get a valid response, `Hello bob!`.

Comment: Ian: Thanks for the feedback. I will go back and play with the bare essentials. Note:: When I substituted Method="*", I was able to get it to work. Not sure why....

Comment: - "Method not allowed". I was testing using Postman.  Here is my test code:  http://localhost:61047/CalculatorService.svc/json/TestPost. The only other thing I can think of which is worth mentioning is that I've got my service set up as the following pattern:  CalculatorServiceLibrary -- CalculatorService.  Thoughts?